# Problem finding eigenvalues of a linear map on an extension field

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be an extension field of $K$ and let $\alpha$ be in $F$, so we can see $F$ as our vector space and $K$ as its scalar. I want to calculate eigenvalues of linear map $m_\alpha: x \rightarrow \alpha x$ from field $F$ to itself. Now, by definition of eigenvalue, we have $m_\alpha(v) = \lambda v$ where $\lambda$ is our eigenvalue but equality $\alpha v = \lambda v$ results in $\alpha = \lambda$ which is a contradiction since $\alpha$ is in $F$ and is not necessarily a scalar.

where is my error? how should I find eigenvalues?

Comment: For $\alpha\in F\setminus K$ the $K$-linear map $m_\alpha\colon F\to F$ has no eigenvalues in $K$ and you just proved that. There's no error.

Comment: @Christoph mmm really? trace of linear transformation $m_\alpha$ is equal to sum of eigenvalues (am I right?) so I didn't expect that. Actually I wanted to find characteristic polynomial of $m_\alpha$ but it seems that i don't know any other way besides finding eigenvalues and form a polynomial with eigenvalues as its roots! do you have any clue?

Comment: No, "trace equals sum of eigenvalues" is only true when the characteristic polynomial factors into linear factors, which isn't the case for $m_\alpha$ as a $K$-linear map, when $\alpha\notin K$. Consider the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ which has no real eigenvalues ($\chi=(X-1)^2+1>0$) but trace $2$. This can be regarded as $m_\alpha\colon\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ for $\alpha=1+\mathrm i$ and the $\Bbb R$-basis $\{1,\mathrm i\}$ of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I edited tags of original post. I thought this problem could have some relation to finite fields since I was solving questions of related topics (field trace and norms and etc) but was just my lack of knowledge in linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the operation will have no eigenvalues (in $K$). Try thinking of it with the example $F = \mathbb{C}$ and $K = R$. You can consider $\mathbb{C}$ to be a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Then multiplication by $\alpha = (a+bi)$ represent a linear transformation represented by the matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}a & -b \\ b & a\end{array}\right]$$ (with respect to the basis $\{1,i\}$ )

You will find that this matrix has no real eigenvalues, just as your argument suggests. That is to say the operation over the 2-dimensional real vector space $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $z\rightarrow \alpha z$ has no (real) eigenvalues.

Note that you can also consider $\mathbb{C}$ to be a one-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ in which case the operation $z \rightarrow \alpha z$ has one eigenvalue, $\alpha$.